# Passing a numpy array into placeholder tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

So i have an array of question id:

```
ques = [2 1 5 2 1 3]
```

which is of shape (6,)

and I'm using this array to be passed into an input placeholder where:

```
class RNN:
    def initialize(self):
       self.X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.int32) #[batch size, max length]
```

However, I'm getting the error saying:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (6,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', 
which has shape '(?, ?)'
```

Would appreciate some help on this

Comment: Change `shape=[None, None]` to `shape=[None,]` or change `ques` to `[[2],[1],[5],[2],[1],[3]]` by `ques=ques[:,np.newaxis]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your array of question id has 1 dimenison while your placeholder expects an input with 2 dimesions.

Suppose that the batch_size is set to 1 in your example then:

```
ques = np.array([[2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3]])
```

and

```
x=tf.placeholder(shape=(None,None), dtype=tf.float32)
```

will work fine.